# How can I select records based on this specific criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and `SSMS` for executing my `T-SQL` queries.

I have the following `SQL` table (extract) called `Table1`:

```
BkgID   ProfileID  ArrivalDate
 872      50        2018-01-03
 876      50        2018-01-03
 911      64        2018-02-15
 924      64        2018-04-15
 950      72        2018-05-04
```

I need my T-SQL query to give me the following output:

```
BkgID   ProfileID  ArrivalDate
 872      50        2018-01-03
 911      64        2018-02-15
 924      64        2018-04-15
 950      72        2018-05-04
```

The logic is that the query must list `ProfileID`s which have same `ArrivalDate` only once. The `BkgID` it chooses to list in such scenario is not important.

How do I write such a query?

Comment: You can easily achieve this using `ROW_NUMBER`. If you google this keyword you will find many examples of how to use this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to achieve this. The `ORDER BY` will determine which record gets first in the ordering of each partition.

```
;WITH RankingByProfile AS 
(
    SELECT
        T.BkgID,
        T.ProfileID,
        T.ArrivalDate,
        Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.ProfileID, T.ArrivalDate ORDER BY T.BkgID ASC)
    FROM
        Table1 AS T
)
SELECT
    R.BkgID,
    R.ProfileID,
    R.ArrivalDate
FROM
    RankingByProfile AS R
WHERE
    R.Ranking = 1
```

You can also use `GROUP BY` and retrieve the `MIN(BkgID)`, but you won't be able to access other columns without aggregate functions.

```
SELECT
    MinBkgID = MIN(T.BkgID),
    T.ProfileID,
    T.ArrivalDate
FROM
    Table1 AS T
GROUP BY
    T.ProfileID,
    T.ArrivalDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select BkgID, ProfileID, ArrivalDate
from (
  select BkgID, ProfileID, ArrivalDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProfileID, ArrivalDate Order By BkgID) RowIdx
  from yourTable)
where RowIdx = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *correlation* approach :

```
select t.*
from table t
where BkgID = (select top 1 t1.BkgID
               from table t1
               where t1.ProfileID = t.ProfileID and t1.ArrivalDate = t.ArrivalDate
               order by t1.BkgID asc
              );
```

This assumes `ArrivalDate` has some reasonable `date` format else use `cast()` function.